# Do I need to wash my tongs between handling raw meat in pan?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, raw-meat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I ensure food safety if my cooking utensils have touched raw meat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10315/how-can-i-ensure-food-safety-if-my-cooking-utensils-have-touched-raw-meat)

I tend to be over careful when handling raw meat when cooking. However, I think it is simply ignorance about what is safe within reason.

My actual question in this case is one that I've wondered for awhile now—when doing stir fry, I use raw chicken and cook it accordingly. After each time I use the tongs to move around the chicken throughout the cooking, I wash the tongs with soap and water. Is this really necessary or can I use the tongs the entire time as I cook the meal without washing them. I keep thinking that the raw juices are going to stay on the tongs and get on to the parts of the meal near the end before I serve it. Am I just being overly-paranoid?